# A computed property name in a type literal must refer to an expression whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface, partial

Ultimately I would like to compute something as below

```js
const configOne = {
  default: {master: 0},
  sg: {master: 1},
}

const configTwo = {
  default: {master: 1}
}
```

Basically the `object` must have the `default` as mandatory properties, then the remaining properties can be optional, but they must be of country prefix. Below is the attempt I have

```js
enum CID {
  'tw',
  'sg',
  'vn',
}

interface IIndividualConfig {
  master: 0 | 1;
}

type IConfig = {
  default: IIndividualConfig;
  [key in CID]?: IIndividualConfig;
}


const configOne: IConfig = {
  default: { master: 0 },
  sg: {master: 1}
}


const configTwo: IConfig = {
  default: { master: 1 }
}
```

And below is the error I've got at `[key in CID]`

```js
A computed property name in a type literal must refer to an expression whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type.ts(1170)
A computed property name must be of type 'string', 'number', 'symbol', or 'any'.ts(2464)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem occurs because you've defined `default` in the definition while using `index signature` such as below

```js
type IConfig = {
  default: IIndividualConfig; // <= Causing error
  [key in CID]?: IIndividualConfig;
}
```

Possible Workaround 1:

```js
type IConfig = {
  [key in CID | 'default']?: IIndividualConfig;
}
```

This will not gives you error, but probably doesn't 100% fit the use case, since `default` is no longer mandatory. Hence may want to look at option 2

Workaround 2:

```js
type IDefaultConfig = { default: IIndividualConfig; }
type IConfig = IDefaultConfig & {[key in CID]?: IIndividualConfig; };
```

Now by using `intersection`, we combined two types into a single type, `default` will be mandatory, and other key are optional and they must be of type `CID` if defined